# shell script to list directories in decreasing order of disk usage

Tags: bash, disk-space-utilization, shell-scripting

I am looking for a shell script for Ubuntu Server that lists the disk usage of directories in a decreasing order. It should not list subfolders (recursively). The behaviour should be similar to the Treesize program on Windows and should be in a human readable format. The disk space of files which are not in a folder can be grouped together as one value.
For example:

```
4G    software
2G    terry
500M  thomas
50M   Files
```

Or, should I just use ncdu?
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=ncdu

Answer (score 2):

This handy one-liner worked in root's directory on one of my servers.

```
root@server:~# du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr
29M     .
19M     ./.cache
48K     ./.ssh
24K     ./.ssh.bkup
16K     ./.local
12K     ./scripts
12K     ./.dbus
12K     ./.config
8.0K    ./.synaptic
8.0K    ./.hplip
8.0K    ./.gnupg
4.0K    ./.gvfs
4.0K    ./.gconf
```